# EmitMapper and ValueInjecter with IList

Tags: c#, automapper, valueinjecter, emitmapper

I'm running a performance test for **AutoMapper**, **FasMapper**, **ValueInjecter** and **EmitMapper** and I'm facing problem only with **EmitMapper** and **ValueInjecter** when I try to map list of types `IList<T>`

That's the code I user for all mappers:

```
adapter.Adapt<IList<VacationModel>, IList<VacationDto>>(source));
```

That is my adapter implementation for **EmitMapper**:

```
    public TTarget Adapt<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
    {
        return ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<TSource, TTarget>().Map(source);
    }
```

That is for **ValueInjecter**:

```
    public TTarget Adapt<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TSource, TTarget>(source);
    }
```

I have a single interface that holds the method `Adapt<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)`

What am I doning wrong? It's working for **AutoMapper** and **FastMapper** tho! If I change to `List<T>` it works for all mappers.

Comment: for valueinjecter you'll have to do a loop if you want to map a collection

Comment: Ok, it works, but after that ValueInjecter lost by far winning only agains AutoMapper. Do you think this is going to be improved?

Comment: depends how you define Mapper.AddMap, you could use InjectFrom or you could do a.p1 = b.p1; ( if performance if very important for that particular mapping); you can look here: https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter/blob/master/Tests/MapperTests.cs see the commented code inside AddMap

Comment: Yeah, so, it's not about a particular mapping...it's about a decision which mapper we should use. As we use an abstract `ITypeAdapter`, this should be as generic as possible in case we need to switch the mapper in the future (this is used in several projects in our company, so if we switch the mapper, we don't want side effects). If you have an idea of how to create an abstraction for mappings that also fits for ValueInjecter, let me know. I was really impressed of ValueInjecter...Merry Xmas!